Is a manifold still a manifold after attaching a cell
This question arises as a side product when I was doing a research project.
Let $M$ be a closed surface (compact, smooth manifold without boundary and of dimension $2$)  with negative curvature. Let $\gamma :\mathbb{S}^1 \to M$ be an embedding $M$. Suppose $\gamma$ is such that $M\setminus \gamma([0,1])$ has finitely many connected components $C_1 , \cdots , C_k$, and that each one of them has the whole $\gamma$ as its boundary. My question is:
Is it true that for each $C_i$ the following procedure is possible? One can attach a $2$-cell to $C_i$ along its boundary $\gamma$, such that the resulting space $C'_i$ is a topological manifold. Moreover, the Riemannian metric on $C_i$ (inherit from $M$) can be extended to $C'_i$ smoothly so that $C'_i$ also becomes a Riemannian manifold.
If not, are there conditions to be put on $\gamma$ so that this becomes affirmative?
Also, I guess it might be helpful to mention the original setting I'm intersted in. $\gamma$ is the length-minimizing geodesic in the free homotopy class $g$ of $M$ (it is a fact that for any commpact manifold with negative sectional curvature, there is exactly one geodesic in each free homotopy class that minimizes length), and $g$ belongs to the commutator group. What I would like to do is to show that $\gamma$ divides $M$ into several connected componnets, and I can select one of them to perform the attaching as described above. The picture I have in mind is $\gamma$ being a loop on the 'handle' of a torus of genus. $2$, as draw below.

I would be much grateful for any comment or suggestion on references.

Have you analyzed what a neighborhood of $\gamma$ would look like (even locally) in the union of $M$ and your cell?

What is your math background and how much topology do you know?
